# How do I properly pass a hex value into a C dll in Python ctypes?

Tags: python, c, hex, ctypes

I am calling a C DLL from python using ctypes. For most of the functions all is working fine. But...now I have a function that requires a hex constant for input and I cannot seem to pass it correctly.

I do not have the C source, but from the documentation, the function definition is like:

```
sensv_bn* NewSensvToFinding_bn (const node_bn* Qnode, const nodelist_bn* Vnodes, int what_find)
```

I am almost certain the I am passing `Qnode` and `Vnodes` properly because they are created by other functions in the DLL. The issue is with the `int` called `what_find`.

From the header file that goes with the DLL, I see the line:
`enum {ENTROPY_SENSV = 0x02, REAL_SENSV = 0x04, VARIANCE_SENSV = 0x100, VARIANCE_OF_REAL_SENSV = 0x104};   /* for NewSensvToFinding_bn */`

The value I am trying to pass for `what_find` is the value of `VARIANCE_OF_REAL_SENSV` which is the hex value `0x104`.

I've tried passing this without conversion and also casting it as an int using `ctypes.c_int(0x104)` but the function returns a 0 instead of a pointer. I've also tried passing without conversion with the same result.

Is there a more proper conversion I should perform? I'm a bit of a C n00b so sorry if this is a really naieve question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Python and C let you define integers using hex literals. They are interpreted as base-16, but their *value* is still an integer. It is nothing more than an alternate notation for the same values:

```
>>> 0x02
2
>>> 0x104
260
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_int(0x104)
c_int(260)
```

You can also use octal (`0o404`, or, in python 2 only, `0404`) or binary (`0b100000100`) notation to specify the same integer value.

The signature specifies it wants an `int`, so pass in an integer value. Specify that integer value as a hex literal in your Python source code if you want, but the *C code* just expects an integer value, and doesn't care wether or not you used hexadecimal notation to create that value.

If the function call is not working with the correct constants, then something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. I see you are right and the conversion seems not to be the issue. That's the good news - the bad news is I can't figure out what the problem is, but as you said, it is "something else".

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the issue was that I was getting the 0 returned indicating that the function ran OK. What I needed was the float that the function actually returns which was obtained by using the restype method and setting it to ctypes.c_double. The input hexadecimal issue turned out a red herring, but great to learn how Python and C both handle hex values.